# Call function after directive initialization and loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a question about the directives in AngularJs, because seems like i don't fully understand them.
So the situation is next:
1) There is a directive:

```
// directive
function myDir() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        templateUrl: '/js/shared/directives/myDir/myDir.html',
        controller: 'myDirController',
        scope: {
            myDir: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

2) This directive allows to perform some actions:

```
// directive controller
function myDirController($scope) {
    var something = {};
    var whatevers = [];

    $scope.myDir = {
        createSmth: createSmth,
        setSmthOptions: setSmthOptions,
        addWhatever: addWhatever,
        removeWhatever: removeWhatever
    };

    function createSmth() {
        something = {
            someOption1: someDefaultValue1,
            someOption2: someDefaultValue2,
            someOption3: someDefaultValue3,
        };
    }

    function setSmthOptions(options) {
        angular.extend(something, options);
    }

    function addWhatever(options) {
        var newWhatever = {
            someOption1: someDefaultValue1,
            someOption2: someDefaultValue2,
            anotherOptions: options
        };

        whatevers.push(newWhatever);
    }

    function removeWhatever(whatever) {
        var idx = whatevers.indexOf(whatever);
        whatevers.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}
```

3) This directive's activation function is:

```
activate()
function activate() {
    createSomething();
}
```

And there is a page, where i'm using this directive:

```
// html
...
<div my-dir="vm.myDir"></div>
...

// controller
...
vm.id = $routeParams.id;
...

activate();
function activate() {
    $q.when(loadData()).then(function() {
        initSomething();
    });
}

function loadData() {
    if (!id) {
        vm.model = {
            data: []
        };
        return null;
    } else {
        // makes request to backend
        myService.getData(id)
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.model = data;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }).finally(function() {
                vm.model = vm.model || {
                    data: []
                };
            });
    }
}

function initSomething() {
    if (vm.myDir) {
        vm.myDir.setSmthOptions(vm.smthOptions);

        vm.whateverOptions.forEach(function (option) {
            vm.myDir.addWhatever(option);
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the directive can be initialized after getting data, because in case of id = undefined, we create default model. i'm sorry, but i don't want to use $timeout, because i think that it looks ugly =.

Now i'm using next solution:

```
var watcher = $scope.$watch(
    function () {
        return {
            model: $scope.vm.model,
            myDir: $scope.vm.myDir
        };
    },
    function (newObj) {
        if (newObj.model && newObj.myDir) {
            initSomething();
            watcher();
        }
    },
    true
);
```

But i'm not sure that it's fine to use it. And maybe there's better solution.

**And the question is: how should i fix this issue? How can i call function after loading data and initializing directive?**

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` will trigger the digest cycle in the next phase, probably if you are looking for some performance related you could use `$scope.$evalAsync()`. Here is a neat article on this subject.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: as i said, i don't want to use $timeout, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your service call is asyncrhonous. So when the loadData function completes, and the service call is made, the vm.model is not initialized yet. You can update your code to something like this:

```js
function activate() {
    loadData().then(function() {
        initSomething();
    });
}

function loadData() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (!id) {
        vm.model = vm.model || {
            data: []
        };
        return $q.resolve();
    } // makes request to backend
    else {
        myService.getData(id)
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.model = data;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }).finally(function() {
                vm.model = vm.model || {
                    data: []
                };
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}
```

Comment: i can't understand you answer.. if your advice is to use $q.defer() -- $q.when() makes the same thing (converting sync and async functions to async), and i know that, and i'm using that. But the question was about another problem =\